# Avoiding Kivy widgets occupying the whole screen

Tags: python, kivy

I created a button 'Add InputBox' that will add an input box once the 
user presses it since i won't be knowing the number of InputBoxes the 
user may require.

These InputBoxes should be arranged vertically such that each one added
will be created at a specific position right below the previous one
without considering the size_hint (even if it's one input box, it 
should not cover the screen. If i told it to be at position (0, 10), it 
should not span past that position).

I tried the BoxLayout whose first InputBox created covered the 
whole screen. The second one takes up 50% of the screen. The 3rd one, 
1/3 of the screen and so on.

I checked out the FloatLayout too with the code below:

```
class NextWindow(Screen):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(NextWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.count_box = 1
    self.layout = FloatLayout()

def addInputBox(self, obj):
    inputBox = TextInput(multiline=False,size_hint=(0.2, 0.05),
                         pos_hint={'top': self.count_box})

    if self.count_box < 150:
        self.count_box = self.count_box + 10   #Changes the value of the position
        self.layout.add_widget(inputBox)       #so that the next InputBox is created

    else:                                      #under the previous one.
        pass #When 14 InputBoxes have been created
```

At the press of the button
'Add InputBox', the value of self.count_box is changed so that the value of
'top' changes after each call so that the next InputBox goes under the previous one.

This did not take up the whole screen. It displayed just the first InputBox but subsequent ones are not shown on the screen when 'Add InputBox' is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

This stems from a poor understanding of the property pos_hint. A way to carry it out is to ignore pos_hint and supply the actual positional property, 'pos'. The value of 'pos' is changed after every click of the 'Add Course' button.